# How to install h5py (+numpy+libhdf5+...) as non-root on a Debian Linux system

Tags: python, numpy, debian, scipy, hdf5

I need to install the h5py Python module, and all its absent dependencies, on a Debian Linux system.  This task is complicated by the following:

1. I don't have any superuser privileges on this system (no sudo, no root password, etc.);
2. the rest of the code I am using requires version 2.7 of Python, which is not the default version installed in this system (although Python 2.7 is available under /opt/python-2.7.1).

The ideal solution would be one that would enable me to use the dependency info in the python-h5py Debian package (wheezy release) to orchestrate the installation of all the missing prerequisites for h5py.  Is there a way to do this?  If so how can I specify the version of Python under /opt/python-2.7.1 as the one to use?

Any suggestions on how best to do this would be appreciated!

Comment: Is hdf5 already installed on your system or do you have to do a userland install for that too?

Comment: hdf5 is installed, but it's a version older than that required by the version of h5py I want, so yes, I need to install hdf5 as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be possible using [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv). You would create a virtualenv like this (at the command line):

```
virtualenv -p /opt/python-2.7.1 mypythonenv
```

Last bit is the name of a new folder for the environment to go in.

Then:

```
cd mypythonenv
source bin/activate
```

Then you can install whatever Python modules you want, and they will be installed in the virtualenv, without requiring any superuser privileges. As far as I know, you can't use .deb packages there, but you can use Python installers like pip or easy_install inside it.

Comment: Have you *ever* installed and *run* numpy on Debian using the pip or easy_install as you say?

Comment: @kjo: I use Ubuntu. I've installed numpy from source at some point, although I don't think I used one of the installers. It needs certain header files to link against, so it may be easier to compile it on a system where you can install the necessary packages, and transfer it across.

Comment: @sygi Now I would recommend installing [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads), or its cousin Miniconda if you prefer a small initial download followed by installing more packages yourself. That can install libraries like libhdf5 without requiring root access. It was not available in 2011, though.

Answer (score 1):

This is overkill and not a Free solution, but you can install [Enthought Python Distribution](http://www.enthought.com/products/epd.php).  HDF5, h5py and (my favorite) pytables come for free.  Building numpy is a pain and it is often easier to let someone do the packaging for you.  It is free for academic usage.