# How to install numpy in a virtualenv on Debian?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pip, easy-install

(NB: see [**this other post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442754/how-to-install-h5py-numpylibhdf5-as-non-root-on-a-debian-linux-system) for why I am not using dpkg/apt-get/etc. for this installation.)

I can install numpy in a virtualenv on Debian with, e.g., pip:

```
(base)[1778]% pip -v install numpy
Downloading/unpacking numpy
 ...
<output omitted>
 ...
Successfully installed numpy
Cleaning up...
  Removing temporary dir /home/jones/.virtualenvs/base/build...
```

But immediately after this:

```
(base)[1779]% python
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jun 22 2011, 15:39:05)
[GCC 4.3.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy
>>> ^D
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I found the problem.  It turns out that, even though my virtualenv is active (see the `(base)` prefix to the command-line prompts in the screen interaction snippets above), I *still* need to tell pip to use it.  E.g. after running something like

```
pip -E /path/to/virtualenv install numpy
```

then importing numpy within an interactive python session succeeds (whether the imported module is functional, I don't know yet).

This is absurd: my virtualenv is active, and the pip executable I'm running is the one installed *in that virtualenv*:

```
(base)[1801] which pip
/home/jones/.virtualenvs/base/bin/pip
```

So what's the point of having a virtualenv if pip will not use it by default???

Comment: There is no -E option in 1.5 version  and the way to install it  $ /home$USER/.."path to virtualenv/ENV"./virtualenv/ENV/bin/pip  install numpy

Comment: This drove me crazy and makes no sense why it would only affect pandas/numpy but not other packages.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that your virtualenv is not actually active?

You might also run into problems with this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-virtualenv/+bug/780220

There is a similar question here: [Windows + virtualenv + pip + NumPy (problems when installing NumPy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114115/windows-virtualenv-pip-numpy-problems-when-installing-numpy)
perhaps some of the answers there may help you.

Answer (score 0):

regarding the last error for command:

```
pip -E /path/to/virtualenv install numpy
```

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Here is solution to that problem.

Upgrade to latest virtualenv:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade virtualenv
```

create your python virtualenv and run

```
pip -E /path/to/virtualenv install numpy
```

Regards, Karlo.

Comment: pip version 1.5 has no -E option.