# Install python-numpy in the Virtualenv environment

Tags: python, numpy, ubuntu-12.04, virtualenv

I would like to install the python-numpy in the Virtualenv environment. My system is Ubuntu 12.04, and my python is 2.7.5. First I installed the Virtualenv by

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv
```

And then set up an environment by

```
$ mkdir myproject
$ cd myproject
$ virtualenv venv
New python executable in venv/bin/python
Installing distribute............done.
```

Activated it by

```
$ . venv/bin/activate
```

Installed python-numpy in the environment by

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-numpy
```

However, I tried to import numpy in python in the environment after all steps above. Python told me "No modules named numpy". Whereas, numpy could be imported in Python globally. I tried to remove and install many times but it does not work. I am a beginner of both Python and Linux.

Comment: try to set the environment variable `PYTHONPATH` pointing to the folder where your numpy module is, in Windows it is `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages`

Comment: Could you please let me know how to set PYTHONPATH? I am a very beginner. Thank you

Comment: try: `export PYTHONPATH=path_to_site_packages...` let me know if this worked...

Comment: @SaulloCastro Thank you so much! It works! It has confused me many days!

Comment: I posted it as an answer so that you can accept it... ;)

Answer (score 8):

`apt-get` will still install modules globally, even when you're in your new `virtualenv`.

You should either use `pip install numpy` from within your virtual environment (easiest way), or else compile and install `numpy` from source using the `setup.py` file in the root of the source directory (slightly harder way, [see here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/install.html#building-from-source)).

I'd also thoroughly recommend you take a look at [`virtualenvwrapper`](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), which makes managing virtual environments much friendlier.

### Edit:

You should **not** be using `sudo`, either to create your virtual environment or to install things within it - it's a directory in your home folder, you don't need elevated permissions to make changes to it. If you use `sudo`, `pip` will make changes to your global site packages, not to your virtual environment, hence why you weren't able to install `numpy` locally.

Another thing to consider is that <s>by default, new `virtualenvs` will inherit from the global `site-packages` - i.e. if Python can't find a module locally within your `virtualenv`, Python will also look in your global site packages</s> *****. In your case, since you'd already installed `numpy` globally (using `apt-get`), when you then try to `pip install numpy` in your virtual environment, `pip` sees that `numpy` is already in your Python path and doesn't install it locally.

You could:

1. Pass the `--no-site-packages` option when you create your `virtualenv`. This prevents the new `virtualenv` from inheriting from the global site packages, so everything must be installed locally.
2. Force `pip` to install/upgrade `numpy` locally, e.g. using `pip install -U --force numpy`

---

***** [As of v1.7](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/blob/develop/docs/changes.rst#17-2011-11-30), the default behaviour of `virtualenv` is to not include the global `site-packages` directory. You can override this by passing the `--system-site-packages` flag when creating a new virtual environment.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried to use the pip in virtualenv. It has been successfully installed (Successfully installed numpy
Cleaning up...), but I till did not work when I imported numpy in virtualenv.

Comment: Can you check that a `numpy` directory exists in `venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`?

Comment: Also can you check the output of `which python` when you're in your `virtualenv` - it should give you something like `/home/myname/myproject/venv/bin/python` rather than your global python.

Comment: No, it is not there, but why it said installed successfully :(

Comment: The output of which python is "/home/kevin/python/Python-2.7.5/myproject/flask/venv/bin/python"

Comment: You didn't use `sudo` when you ran `pip install numpy` in your `virtualenv`, did you?

Comment: I did. When I typed again, it said "Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages", which shows its location is not in the virtualenv.

Comment: Hi @ali_m , problem solved! I pointed the PYTHONPATH to where the global numpy locate and it works. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Thanks for your added comment. Learn a lot from that. :)

Comment: the do not use `sudo` part is the key.

Answer (score 1):

meddling with PYTHONPATH for site-packages indeed defeats the purpose of virtalenv. what worked for me was to specify the env i wanted the packages to be installed in via pip

example:

```
pip -E /home/proj1
```

where `proj1` was created using virtualenv.

reference: [how to install numpy in a virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6453320/1463143)