# how to resolve ImportError: No module named 'numpy.matrixlib' in pycharm?

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm

When I am using PyCharm it is suddenly showing me the below `ImportError` (and a bunch of other errors). I don't think it is necessary to add `numpy` in PyCharm IDE. So can you help me resolve this problem?

I have tried using a different python version to resolve this problem but it hasn't helped.

The code is:

```py
import numpy as np
import time

import sys

S = range(1000)
print(sys.getsizeof(5) * len(S))

D = np.arange(1000)
print(D.size * D.itemsize)
```

I am getting this error for the above code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 3, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "D:/pyprog/test].py", line 2, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\pyprog\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 145, in <module>
    from . import lib
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\pyprog\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .index_tricks import *
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\pyprog\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\index_tricks.py", line 13, in <module>
    import numpy.matrixlib as matrixlib
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ImportError: No module named 'numpy.matrixlib'
```

Comment: Formatting your question appropriately (e.g. code) could expedite the answer.

Comment: sir, for any usage of  numpy  I am getting the same error

Comment: how do I install numpy in the venv in windows environment

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with installing `numpy` in `virtualenv`. Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204134/install-python-numpy-in-the-virtualenv-environment) (linux) or [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114115/windows-virtualenv-pip-numpy-problems-when-installing-numpy?rq=1) (windows) for instructions on how to install `numpy` in the `venv` or use a non-virtualized runtime with `numpy` installed.

Comment: how do I install numpy in the venv in windows environment?

Comment: Added a reference (easy to find via search on StackOverflow) to installation help for Windows.