# err when installing numpy under virtualenv

Tags: linux, numpy, pip, virtualenv, redhat

I want to install numpy under virtualenv. I have follow the way described in [How to install numpy in a virtualenv on Debian?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451821/how-to-install-numpy-in-a-virtualenv-on-debian) . I use cmd line: `/home/szh702/virtenv/bin/pip install numpy` (`virtenv` is the name I set up the virtualenv as), but still get an err msg  as following:

```
Command /home/szh702/virtenv/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/home/szh702/virtenv/build/numpy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-soyglwkq-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/szh702/virtenv/include/site/python3.4 failed with error code 1 in /home/szh702/virtenv/build/numpy
Storing debug log for failure in /home/szh702/.pip/pip.log
```

can some one be so kind to tell me how to solve it?

Comment: What does the log say?

Comment: thx. but the log is too long. I just list some warnings and the last error here:    Running from numpy source directory.
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found
    
    reading manifest file 'pip-egg-info/numpy.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution

Comment: error: Command "gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -I/opt/rh/rh-python34/root/usr/include -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.4/numpy/core/include/numpy  ...

Comment: I HAVE INSTALLED NUMPY SUCCESSFULLY UNDER SCL PYTHON27 INSTEAD OF RH-PYTHON34. But scipy can hardly be installed!!!!